# winsock - Sender UDP socket not bound to the desired port

Tags: udp, winsock

Below you can see my code that implements a pretty basic UDP sender in C++ with Winsock. The thing is that no matter how many times I run the code, the socket (the listenSocket) gets bound to a different UDP port. Is there any specific reason for this? Am I doing some mistake in my code?

thanks

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;    
    SOCKADDR_IN myAddress;
    SOCKADDR_IN targetAddress;

    int myPort = 60888;
    const char *myIP = "192.168.0.1";
    int remotePort = 2048;
    const char *remoteIP = "192.168.0.2";

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET SendSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET acceptSocket;

    char cBuffer[1024] = "Test Buffer";
    int nBytesSent = 0;
    int nBufSize = strlen(cBuffer);
    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    if( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData ) != NO_ERROR )
    {
        cerr<<"Socket Initialization: Error with WSAStartup\n";
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(10);
    }

    ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    SendSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET or SendSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr<<"Socket Initialization: Error creating socket"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(11);
    }

    //bind
    myAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(myIP);
    myAddress.sin_port = htons(myPort);

    targetAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    targetAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(remoteIP);
    targetAddress.sin_port = htons(remotePort);

    if(bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, sizeof(myAddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr<<"ServerSocket: Failed to connect\n";
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(14);
    }
    else
        printf("Server: bind() is OK.\n");

    nBytesSent = sendto(SendSocket, cBuffer, nBufSize, 0,
                 (SOCKADDR *) &targetAddress,
                 sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));    

    printf("Everything is ok\n");

    system("PAUSE");

    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    closesocket(SendSocket);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT: Maybe I was not so clear. What I do with this code is to send some data to a remote PC. But what is required is that the UDP segments should appear to be originated from a specific port. How can this be done? Is it wrong what I'm doing here? Now that I'm thinking of it, I guess it is wrong indeed. The SendSocket and ListenSocket don't have any connection, correct? So, how can I make it that the UDP segments appear to originate from a specific UDP port? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling `bind()` on `SendSocket` before sending data with it, so WinSock is free to bind that socket to whatever random local IP/Port it needs to.  If you have to send data with a specific source IP/Port every time, you have to `bind()` to that IP/Port first.  If that local IP/Port is the same pair you are binding `ListenSocket` to, then you don't need to use two separate sockets to begin with.  You can send data with the same socket that is listening for incoming data.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, I was really confused (although it is so simple). I hadn't realized that a socket can be bound to a local ip/port no matter if we listen to incoming data or transmit from this socket.

Comment: 8 years later, I'm still confused. Are you saying (assuming `ListenSocket != SendSocket`) that in addition to calling

`bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, sizeof(myAddress))`

you also need to call

`bind(SendSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &myAddress, sizeof(myAddress))` ?

That second call returns `-1`.

Comment: More specifically, I get the error code 10048 (address already in use). Looks to me like I can't bind the same address to both `ListenSocket` and the `SendSocket`, then? Does this mean that this reply should read 

_If that local IP/Port is the same pair you are binding `ListenSocket` to, then you *cannot* use two separate sockets to begin with. You *must* send data with the same socket that is listening for incoming data_?